# How to convert response body in Json using play framework

Tags: json, scala, twitter, playframework, ws-client

```
 override def accessToken(): ServiceCall[RequestTokenLogIn, Done] = {
request=>
  val a=request.oauth_token.get
  val b=request.oauth_verifier.get
  val url=s"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=$a&oauth_verifier=$b"
  ws.url(url).withMethod("POST").get().map{
    res=>
   println(res.body)
  }
```

The output which I am getting on terminal is
`oauth_token=xxxxxxxxx&oauth_token_secret=xxxxxxx&user_id=xxxxxxxxx&screen_name=xxxxx`

I want to convert this response in json format.like

```
{
oauth_token:"",
token_secret:"",
}
```

When Calling `res.json.toString` its not converting into jsValue.
Is there any other way or am I missing something?

Comment: Why aren't you using POST oauth2/token ? You can find its documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/token. You can read about Json reads, and writes, which you have built-in in your play app. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: So how to get user_id, screen_name, oauth_token ans oauth_secret_token. Aouth 2.0 only response access_token.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/access_token) twitter publishes, it seems that the response is not a valid json. Therefore you cannot convert it automagically.
As I see it you have 2 options, which you are not going to like. In both options you have to do string manipulations.

The first option, which I like less, is actually building the json:

```
print(s"""{ \n\t"${res.body.replace("=", "\": \"").replace("&", "\"\n\t\"")}" \n}""")
```

The second option, is to extract the variables into a case class, and let [play-json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson) build the json string for you:

```
case class TwitterAuthToken(oauth_token: String, oauth_token_secret: String, user_id: Long, screen_name: String)
object TwitterAuthToken {
  implicit val format: OFormat[TwitterAuthToken] = Json.format[TwitterAuthToken]
}
 
val splitResponse = res.body.split('&').map(_.split('=')).map(pair => (pair(0), pair(1))).toMap
val twitterAuthToken = TwitterAuthToken(
  oauth_token = splitResponse("oauth_token"),
  oauth_token_secret = splitResponse("oauth_token_secret"),
  user_id = splitResponse("user_id").toLong,
  screen_name = splitResponse("screen_name")
)

print(Json.toJsObject(twitterAuthToken))
```

I'll note that `Json.toJsObject(twitterAuthToken)` returns JsObject, which you can serialize, and deserialize.

I am not familiar with any option to modify the delimiters of the json being parsed by play-json. Given an existing json you can manipulate the paths from the json into the case class. But that is not what you are seeking for.

I am not sure if it is requires, but in the second option you can define user_id as long, which is harder in the first option.